# Printing bitmap from Silverlight - image blurry

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, printing

I'm trying to print image from Silverlight application. I have pretty good quality scans (TIFF) with resolution 1696x2200

When I print - I get `PrintableArea` from `PrintDocument` and it's 816x1056

What I do - I resize bitmap to Printable area (to fit document to page) and result I get is blurry image. I understand this is scaling problem (most likely), but how do I scale properly so it looks good? When I display document inside Image and just set image size - it looks good.

For resizing I'm using WriteableBitmapEx extensions and tried both types of resize (Nearest neighbor and bilinear)

Code:

```
var printDocument = new PrintDocument(); 

            printDocument.PrintPage += (s, ea) =>
                {
                    var printableArea = ea.PrintableArea;

                    var bitmap = this.currentPreviewPage.FullBitmap.Resize((int)printableArea.Width, (int)printableArea.Height, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);

                    var image = new Image { Source = bitmap };
                    var canvas = new Canvas { Width = bitmap.PixelWidth, Height = bitmap.PixelHeight };
                    canvas.Children.Add(image);

                    ea.PageVisual = canvas; 
                    ea.HasMorePages = false;
                }; 

            printDocument.PrintBitmap("Silverlight Bitmap Print");
```

How document looks on screen (inside Image)

[image]

And this is printed:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using the WriteableBitmapEx extensions, when declaring your `Image` element, try setting the [Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch%28VS.95%29.aspx) property so that it stretches based on your maximum specified dimensions:

```
var image = new Image { Source = bitmap, Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill };
```

Comment: Almost! This didn't work but point into right direction. Even if I set size on Canvas - Image won't Stretch. But it was easy to solve: `new Image { Width = ..., Height = .... }` and I got nice picture

Answer (score 0):

Blilinear filter tends to blur images.You may want to try WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.NearestNeighbor instead to see if you get better results

Comment: Than its maze of black squares

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was enough to set UseLayoutRounding="True".